# Iterator и перемещение в одном направлении

Tags: java, коллекции

Верно ли, что в `Java` `Iterator` поддерживает перемещение только в одном направлении? Если да, какие причины легли в именно такое перемещение по коллекциям в `Java`?

Comment: Основное назначение итераторов - не перемещение по коллекции, а перебор элементов коллекции. Итератор в java, на мой взгляд, итак слишком многословен - метод `remove` кажется лишним, будто затесался от другого интерфейса

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), он однонаправленнный и имеет методы `next()` и `hasNext()`, а есть [ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html), он двунаправленный, в нем есть как `next()` и `hasNext()`, так и `previous()` и `hasPrevious()`. Какую реализация брать в каком случае - задача программиста. Касательно того, в какой коллекции какой итератор используется в уже реализовннных коллекциях, это вопрос собственно реализации коллекции.

Answer (score 1):

А что вас не устраивает? Да `Iterator` это интерфейс, который позволяет "двигаться" только в одном направлении - направление зависит от имплементации/реализации интерфейса в конкретной коллекции - можно сделать собственную реализацию.

Если уж совсем не устраивает пишите свой интерфейс, типа:

```
public interface DoubleDirectionIterator<E> extends Iterator<E> {
   public boolean hasPrev();
   public E prev();
}
```